# Attic HVAC BTU considerations

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, furnace, attic

I live in central New York and will be installing a furnace and coil in my unfinished attic with an A/C unit outside to condition 800 sq/ft of upstairs living space.

The attic a standard overhang (no trusses) with a 6 foot peak and is not insulated except for the 2x6 floor which also has plywood on it. Summers can have 2 week stretches of 90+ degrees and the winter can have single digit temps for 1-2 weeks.

During the summer the attic is unbearably hot and quite cold in the winter.

I am planning to do a 40k furnace and 2 ton A/C unit with sealed and insulated ductwork.

Do I have to take these temperature extremes into consideration? Should I do a 2.5 or 3 ton A/C instead?

Comment: Is the attic insulated? How about the walls? If so, can you add more?

Comment: @JACK The attic floor is insulated. Even if I can add more, the attic itself, where the furnace will live, will still experience the same temperature swings.

Comment: two things:  I'd see about improving the ventilation in the attic. Maybe a thermostatically controlled gable vent fan.  Next:  You'll want to have extra insulation on the ductwork.  Best practice now is to have the ductwork installed in conditioned space.   But that's not very practical in a retrofit.

Comment: We don’t design for the “normal” or “regular” temperatures. We design for the extremes. We want the system to work on those extreme days year around. I’d go with the 3 ton unit and stay away from electric heating coils. Use gas. Electric won’t work at low temperatures below 30 - 35 F.

Comment: Some mechanical/electrical devices have an operating temperature range, usually greater than for a human.  If attic stays in this range you should be okay for operating it.  If not then will need to adjust attic to stay in the range.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Are R8 sleeves the best and easiest way to insulate the ducts? I've read that gable vent fans can actually cause issues. https://www.energyvanguard.com/blog/the-1-reason-power-attic-ventilators-don-t-help/

Comment: @LeeSam Yes, I will be getting a 40k btu gas furnace. The system itself will be in the attic but it will be conditioning the second floor of the house. Do the extreme attic temperatures affect performance?

Comment: @crip659 The attic is not conditioned whatsoever. Summers can have 2 week stretches of 90+ degrees and the winter can have single digit temps for 1-2 weeks .

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  Any system you check to buy, will need to check if it is suppose to work/operate in those temperatures.  Some hi-efficiently gas heaters have been known to have their exhaust vents freeze up in those winter temps.

Comment: What color is the roof? How well are the roof and south and west walls shaded?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Roof is black asphalt shingles. No shade on west nor south side of roof.

Answer (score 1):

You should insulate the system as throughly as possible from the attic space, while it can be effectively uninsulated from, or minimally insulated from, the interior space without negative impact, since that's the space it's controlling.

The attic space should still be effectively ventilated, both to keep the roof cold and prevent ice dams and the resulting leaks in heating season, and to limit the load on the hot side of the insulation in cooling season.

Oversizing the system is easy, and will cost a lot over the life of the system .vs. insulating it really well, which costs more at the start but less over the system lifetime.

Comment: The A/C unit will be outside. Traditional ducted split system. Maybe I should have worded my question better but my main concern is whether there is enough conditioned air loss if the ducts are in such an unconditioned space to warrant a larger BTU/ton rating.

Comment: Put more insulation on/over the ducts, preferably. You mention "R8 sleeves" which is a laughable amount of insulation in central New York state. Bury them under 15" of cellulose blown insulation or fiberglass batts and you'd be getting reasonable. Pay once for insulation or all the time in running costs...

Comment: Very good point, thank you!

Comment: OK, that's resulted in a complete re-write of the answer...

Comment: Sorry for any frustration. I gladly await an updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your situation entirely. You have many rooms. In which case, a mini-spit is not worth the effort. You are going to have to go conventional.

Your space is finished, so there will be no more insulation going in.  The actual sizing of the unit must be based upon losses...

2 TON for an 800 square foot space! It is better to go smaller. It will remove more humidity from the air. You are going for a very uncomfortable cold and damp. A 1 to 1.5 ton unit should have no problem with the job, and you are considering 3 tons. Do you have intent to insulate the attic?

The lower the BTU of the unit, the less power it uses and more it runs. The longer the unit runs, the more the air gets circulated and an even temperature is achieved. This is especially important due to the low ceiling. The longer the A/C unit runs, the dryer the air gets and the cooler it feels. Contrary to popular belief, bigger is not better. The only catch is that the unit must be able to cool the area.

You will need more cooling power if you have poor insulation which will leak out the roof. You will need more cooling power if your staircase is open to the downstairs as the cold air will fall.

Yes, like others said, insulation is epic. Since it is an attic, you probably lack physical space for a bunch of insulation and air flow behind it. Foam it. Foam leaves no space for air to become a problem
in the first place, so condensation will not occur. Just be aware that you are going to want an extreme R-Value because air on the back side will not help the insulation stay cool. Go for that 6 to 10 inches foam and use white shingles to reflect the sun.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mini-splits. My understanding is that I would need a heat-pump mini-split, correct? Temps can reach 0 in the winter. 24k btu cooling and 40k btu of heating? I have 3 bedrooms, a bath, and a hallway so would I need 5 heads? Is this something I could source myself or would I need an HVAC company's help? I am not comfortable with brazing but based on the pictures it uses flare fittings? If the mini-split is installed outside then I would need well over 25 ft of line to reach each room. The attic is a standard overhang and is 6 feet tall at the peak.

Comment: Don't mini-splits also introduce many more points of failure?